# How to apply :contains pseudo class for PhantomJS/CasperJS?

Tags: jquery-selectors, casperjs

Is there a way to select a tag containing specified text like the `:contains` selector does with jQuery in CasperJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject jQuery using ([`clientScripts`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clientscripts) or [`remoteScripts`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#remotescripts)) into the page and select elements based on that in the page context (inside `casper.evaluate()`):

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    remoteScripts:  [
        'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'
    ]
});

casper.start(url, function(){
    var text = this.evaluate(function(){
        return $("div:contains('asdf')").text();
    });
    this.echo(text);
}).run();
```

Note that DOM elements cannot be passed from the page context to the outside. You need to build some representation of the element.

The other possibility is to use the XPath utility of CasperJS to select elements based on text:

```
var casper = require('casper').create(),
    x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start(url, function(){
    this.echo(this.fetchText(x("//div[contains(text(),'asdf')]")));
}).run();
```

The XPath `text()` function is different from jQuery's `:contains()`, because it only gets the text content (single text node) of the current node with looking at its descendants. This can be improve, but still doesn't mean exactly the same thing by looking at descendants:

```
x("//div[.//*[contains(text(),'asdf')]]")
```